# Unable to use groovy Webdriver scripts in WebdriverSampler

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to use groovy script to launch my client using webdriver sampler and it doesn't work as expected.only JavaScript is working with the following code

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //WebDriver classes
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait); //WebDriver classes
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); //captures sampler's start time
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.log.info("Sample started");

WDS.browser.get('https://google.com/');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Groovy syntax](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html) differ from JavaScript, i.e. there is no [JavaImporter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java#JavaImporter_Constructor) there, you should use [`import` keyword](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports) instead
2. There is no `var` keyword in Groovy/Java (unless you're using [Java 10](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/05/25/simplify-local-variable-type-definition-using-the-java-10-var-keyword/)), you need to change it to [`def` keyword](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-syntax.html#_keywords)
3. Assuming all above you need to amend your code to look like:

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait

   def wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,5000);

   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); //captures sampler's start time
   WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
   WDS.log.info("Sample started");

   WDS.browser.get('https://google.com/');
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to get started with Groovy scripting in JMeter

Comment: Thanks for the response Dmitri T and quick one as we are trying to use waits and expected conditions in our webDriver Sampler as below                                                                     `def closeButton = By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Close']")
wait.until(elementToBeClickable(closeButton))
WDS.findElement(closeButton).click(); WDS.browser.findElementByXpath("//button[@aria-label='Close']").click();
WDS.browser.findElementByCss('button[aria-label=Close]').click();` none of the above code works as expected and  there any documentation available for WDS usage in groovy.